# Send emails via mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, asp.net, triggers

So i have a database where every time a project is added by a user, i need to receive an email with all the data added so i can validate and confirm the truefulness of the project.
I'm searching for the syntax but i'm not finding very helpful tips. Would it be easier do this through the backend (asp.net) or mysql (my method of choice) using trigger's?
[The table in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuA8v.png)

i haven't really tried anything bc i'm honestly very lost

Comment: A database is not the place to send emails from.  Your asp.net layer will have libraries to send email and this would be the correct place.